# How can I read a file line by line from the bottom with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a long log file that I need to read from the bottom, line by line, stopping when a certain condition is met, and then returning that line. Also this needs to work on Windows. The file will probably be pretty long, so I don't want to read the entire file and then reverse it.

I'm currently using [reverse-line-reader](https://github.com/paul-em/reverse-line-reader), however it hasn't been updated since 2015 and the async functionality leaves much to be desired.

Every other package I've seen is either [archived](https://github.com/dominictarr/fs-reverse), [requires me to know the number of lines I want ahead of time](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-last-lines), [or doesn't process by lines](https://github.com/soldair/node-fs-backwards-stream).

Is there any way to do this in vanilla Node, or is there a package that I haven't seen that does what I need?

Current code, if it's at all helpful to explain what I need:

```
reverseLineReader.eachLine(this.#path, (raw: string, last: boolean) => {
    if (raw) { // skip blank line at end of file
        const line = JSON.parse(raw)

        if (line.event === 'FSDJump') {
            this.location = new System(line)
            Log.write(`Current location set to ${this.location.name}.`)
            this.emit('ENTERED_NEW_SYSTEM')
            return false // stop reading

        } else if (last) {
            log('Unable to find last hyperspace jump. Searching for last known location.')
            return false
        }
    }
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would use fs.stat to get the file size. Then use fs.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, callback) and a buffer to read in batches from the end. In this case length should be the size of your buffer and position would be the filesize - bufferlength.

Comment: FWIW, `reverse-line-reader` has no production dependencies and is MIT licensed. Aside from the dated API, there's no real risk to using it. You could simply fork it and update it at will as it already provides the solution to your question.

Comment: If efficiency matters, `reverse-line-reader` is not very efficient.  It reads the file in 1k chunks and opens the file anew, reads 1k, closes the file, then repeats over and over (opening and closing the file for every 1k of the file).  It also use a synchronous file operation at the beginning for getting the length of the file, then uses asynchronous operations later for reading the data.  Most servers don't want any synchronous file operations anywhere.

Comment: @Jeffrey Mixon If I was at all confident in my abilities I would, but I'm new to Node & file system processes, and barely understand the source code of reverse-line-reader, let alone how to modify it haha.
The reason for not liking it is that I need to do a couple things in a row involving reading this file, and the code gets hard to follow being passed around to different functions. Something promise-based would be ideal since I could simply put all the steps in one function, waiting for each promise to return before moving on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic vanilla node implementation of a `readBackwards` method that reads a number of bytes from the end of a file.

For simplicity it opens the file, uses stat to get the file size and then uses read with an offset calculated from the end of the file.

If you need to read more from the end of the file you should call stat outside the method and pass in the size as an argument to not call stat unnecessarily often. Then you can basicly increase the `positionFromEnd` in each iteration by the size of your buffer to have it slide over the file from end to beginning.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const { Buffer } = require("buffer");

function readBackwards(
  file,
  buffer,
  offsetInBuffer,
  length,
  positionFromEnd,
  callback
) {
  fs.open(file, "r", 0666, (err, fd) => {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    fs.fstat(fd, (err, stat) => {
      if (err) return callback(err);

      fs.read(
        fd,
        buffer,
        offsetInBuffer,
        length,
        Math.max(stat.size - length - positionFromEnd, 0),
        (err, bytesRead, buffer) => {
          if (err) return callback(err);

          fs.close(fd, (err) => {
            return callback(err, bytesRead, buffer);
          });
        }
      );
    });
  });
}
```

Try it out here:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/loving-mestorf-hgro1p?file=%2Findex.js%3A8%2C13

Edit:
To read line by line you would concatenate what you have read during iterations until the first line-break occurs. Then you split on the line-break(s) and can process those completed lines before reading more from the file.

Comment: This is missing about 50% of the solution.  Somewhere something has to loop over this and something has to break content into  lines.  And, it's unclear why you open and close for every read operation rather than move that outside the loop that would be required.